# how website like placeit.net add images and text on top of images

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, frontend

I have been trying to figure out how these services (https://placeit.net) **add images on top of other images and text and even change colour**.And how the image uploader marks the place for where to go the custom images/text to be placed to be able to correctly add the same

Comment: It can be done with canvas. The HTML <canvas> element is used to draw graphics, on the fly, via JavaScript. In the old times it was done with Flash.